# I want my discord bot to send a specified user a dm

Tags: python, discord, bots, pycord

I would like my bot to DM someone when their application is denied.

Current code

```
@bot.slash_command(name="deny", description = "deny a users application")
async def deny(ctx, msg: str):
    await ctx.author.send(msg)
```

I would also like this code to check their role to see if they are allowed to deny people.

Answer (score 0):

The only things missing in your code is a user parameter in your function, and to check if the person who issued the command has your desired role.

You could do it this way:

```py
@bot.slash_command(name="deny", description = "deny a users application")
async def deny(ctx, msg: str, user: discord.User):
    role = "" # The ID of the role you want to check if the user has
    for user_role in ctx.author.roles:
        if user_role.id == int(role):
            await ctx.send("User denied!") # Just a visual confirmation for the person, you can change this to whatever you prefer.
            await user.send(msg) # DMs the tagged user with the denial message
            return
```

Have in my mind that if you paste your desired role ID directly as an integer (without it being between "quotation marks"), you don't have to cast it to int when you check if `role.id == int(role)`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@bot.slash_command(name="deny", description = "deny a users application")
async def deny(ctx, msg: str, member: discord.Member):
    role = ("roleid or name")
    if member has role:
       #code
    await member.send(member)
```

Member.send sends it to the user through a dm.

Answer (score -1):

i dont know if i fully understanded your question, but with this code you check if a member has a role and it dms them it their application got accepted or not

```
@bot.command()
async def deny(ctx, member: discord.Member, *,):
    role = "" # put the role id here
    if get(member.roles, id=role):
        channel = await member.create_dm()
        await channel.send("your application has been accepted")
    else:
         ctx.send("your application has been denied")
```

Comment: I don't think that's what OP wanted, he wants to DM a tagged user with the msg parameter. Also, he is using slash_commands. 

While you don't have comments privilege to clarify this sort of things, you shouldn't post answers if you're not sure of what the person wants to do. It's better (and correct) to wait for someone else to answer it, or if the question lacks details you can flag it.